# Save docx into mysql

Tags: mysql, docx, tinybutstrong

I am using the tinybutstrong to generate docx files from a template. 
Currently the generated document will be downloaded as file.
The following code is in use:

```
...
$output_file_name = date('Y_m_d').'CR_Id='.$Id.'.docx';
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, $output_file_name);
exit();
```

But I want to have the generated docx saved directly into mysql as file. 
I have a table in mysql to upload files.

Is that possible?
If yes, then how should the abouve document look like?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad practice to store binary files in a database.

Nevertheless, it is possible to retrieve the binary result of the OpenTBS directly in PHP instead of save it into a file.

Example:

```
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_STRING);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($TBS->Source); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (bin_data) VALUES ('$data')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

See the [documentation](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#show) for more info

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Is that possible to save each downloaded  copy into mysql?
So let me say I am using my submited code to download the file as docx and save an copy into mysql in same time. I would appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: You con retrieve the binary source of the file generated by OpenTBS like any other local file : `$data = file_get_contents($output_file_name);`. Then you can insert it into the database using the end of the snipped above. You should consider to not save file binary content into the database.